# RadRichTextBox ContextMenu Click Event WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, contextmenu

In a scenario i need to handle the click event of a menu inside the default `ContextMenu` of `RadRichTextBox`. Is there anyway that i can get click event of the "Edit Hyperlink" in the ContextMenu?

[image: Hyperlink]

Or do i have any alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `RadMenuItem.Click` event:

```
<telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="rtb" telerik:RadMenuItem.Click="rtb_Click" />
```

---

```
private void rtb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadMenuItem;
    if (item != null && item.Header != null && item.Header.ToString() == "Edit Hyperlink...")
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: On which property i can get and set the Hyperlink value?

Comment: Why do you want the hyperlink value? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to your original question of "is there anyway that i can get click event of the "Edit Hyperlink" in the ContextMenu?". Clicking on Edit Hyperlink brings a dialog that lets you edit the hyperlink. If you want to customize the default context menu you could use a ContextMenuContentBuilder as suggested in the official documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radrichtextbox/ui-for-applying-rich-text-formatting/features-context-menu.

Comment: @mm8 Kindly take a look in this please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115620/contextmenu-hyperlink-in-radrichtextbox-wpf

Comment: @mm8 Yes, but that's my actual scope. I was trying this as an alternative. If possible kindly help me with that.

Comment: I'll take a look at it.